# Why do cordless phone batteries have "this side up" on them?

Tags: batteries

Why do cordless phone batteries have "this side up" on them?

This will not affect how they're connected since they can only be connected one way.

[Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08HCF93LJ) (includes photos of battery with flying leads going to a polarised 2-pin connector).

**More Information (after reading some comments)**

1. Many replacement batteries have this as seen [here](https://www.amazon.com/Cordless-Telephone-Batteries/b/?ie=UTF8&node=172608).
2. These are replacement batteries so it probably isn't for one
   specific type of phone that needs it (though perhaps they're all the
   same in some way).
3. They have a "this side down" on the side you can't see in the
   pictures. At least the ones I have at home do. So "top" is not the
   side with the connectors.
4. They do not have a sticker on the back.

Comment: Presumably so you can see any warning labels without removing them from the device. Just a guess.

Comment: So you don't install them backwards

Comment: that makes no sense ... the cordless phone could be in any position ... usually in a vertical orientation ... maybe the battery pack has a sticky patch on the "underside"

Comment: @VoltageSpike Assuming you meant the polarity - as I said that's impossible. See the connector in the other pictures there.

Comment: @jsotola I have something similar with the same "this side up" (and "this side down" on the other side), and they have no sticker.

Comment: @jsotola up relative to the orientation in the phone. There are many devices that have "this site up" to indicate the installation orientation.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Oh. OK. But why would that matter? besides, cordless batteries usually stand up, so this doesn't seem to make a difference. To make it clear - at least in my batteries, there is also "this side down" on the reverse side - the side not seen in the images in the link.

Comment: It's likely there so people stop asking which way they battery should be. When it reads there, people don't ask that.

Comment: I've seen people shove keyed batteries and connectors in backwards. Anyway its just a guess, really only the designers would know.

Comment: It could also be because of which side the wires come out of the battery pack. It might be a more ideal fit having the wires run on one side vs the other.

Comment: Maybe from bitter experience of users.

Comment: @bunker89320 These are replacement batteries so not for a specific type of phone. Though perhaps all phones are the same in which side would be better.

Comment: Please put the images directly to your questions. The amazon links may disappear soon and your question gets confusing.

Comment: A friend had a sticker on the boot of his car " this side up"... :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a UX issue. The battery is near symmetrical.   If you install them upside down, the contacts will not mate to the connector, they won't work, they probably won't fit, and then you might be tempted to use force to get the lid on, which would then break things.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: The side you can't see in the picture has a "this side down" on it, so "up" and "down" don't mean that.

Comment: @ispiro I described why the OEMs do things. OEMs tend to wrap batteries in clothing to help protect and key it. The items you linked are 3rd party Amazon Marketplace sellers hawking cheap knock-offs off the Alibaba junkstream, so who knows?  Make the product look more legit.

Comment: on battery packs with leads, you're right, it make no sense or difference. On packs with connectors right on the battery pack, it certainly does matter. It's not unreasonable to assume that the cheap manufacturer simply uses the same wrap for many packs of different styles; they likely can't read what it says anyway, and ordering more custom wraps at once saves them money.